# HAproxy SSL handshake failure

Tags: ssl, frontend, config, haproxy, handshake

when i use HAproxy as load balancer, at HTTP termination mode and i tail log of it

(tail -f /var/log/haproxy.log). There are 2 types of log appearing

```
[time] frontend_name/1: SSL handshake failure
```

and

```
[time] frontend_name~ message
```

*frontend_name* is name follow frontend keyword config in /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

I don't know what **/1** and **~** in log message is, and why SSL handshake failure appearing at log has **~**
Can someone help me explain and fix this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`~` after frontend name means connection has been established using SSL/TLS
You can find reference to it in `%ft` entry in the table at: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#8.2.4
About `/1` in `frontend_name/1: SSL handshake failure`:
I can't find it in the docs, but by experimenting i found it's the number of port in frontend, to which connection was attempted and SSL handshake failed.
For config:

```
frontend frontend_name
  bind *:443,*:444 ssl crt <path_to_cert>
  bind *:445 ssl crt <path_to_cert> no-tlsv13
```

If i make TLS1.3 connection to port 445 (e.g. `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:445 -tls1_3`), i will get:

```
frontend_name/3: SSL handshake failure
```

because 445 is 3. port listed in this frontend.

**[UPDATE]**
I found a bit more. [Error log format](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#8.2.5) explains that `/1` in `frontend_name/1` is `bind_name` and can be declared:

```
bind *:443,*:443 ssl crt <path_to_cert> no-tlsv13 name bind_ssl_foo
```

will result in `frontend-name/bind_ssl_foo: SSL handshake failure`.
Unfortunately we can't change error log format.

To learn more we have to make that connection successful and that most likely requires us to lower security (FOR DEBUGGING ONLY!). Normal clients will still negotiate highest security they can, TLS 1.2 or 1.3.

```
bind *:443 ssl crt <path_to_cert> ssl-min-ver TLSv1.0
```

Since haproxy 2.2 default for `ssl-min-ver` is TLSv1.2.
Second step is to log SSL version, negotiated cipher and maybe whole cipherlist send by client by appending `%sslv` `%sslc` and maybe `%[ssl_fc_cipherlist_str]` to your log-format:

```
log-format "your_log_format_here %sslv %sslc %[ssl_fc_cipherlist_str]"
```

If you don't have your own log format you can extend HTTP format:

```
log-format "%ci:%cp [%tr] %ft %b/%s %TR/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Ta %ST %B %CC %CS %tsc %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq %hr %hs %{+Q}r %sslv %sslc %[ssl_fc_cipherlist_str]"
```

To use `ssl_fc_cipherlist_str` we need to set `tune.ssl.capture-cipherlist-size 800` in global section, because default is 0.
`sslv` is SSL/TLS version client connected with.
`sslc` is SSL/TLS cipher client connected with.
`ssl_fc_cipherlist_str` is cipher list client offered when negotiating SSL/TLS connection. It can be long. Use if you are extra curious.

That will append to your logs info like this:

```
TLSv1 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,AES256-SHA,AES128-SHA,TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
```

Match by IP previous errors with current entries and you will know what TLS version and ciphers they were using. Then decide whether to adjust your ciphers or force this client to upgrade their SSL software.

So all required changes below:

```
global
  log /dev/log daemon
  tune.ssl.capture-cipherlist-size 800

frontend frontend_name
  bind *:443 ssl crt <path_to_cert> ssl-min-ver TLSv1.0
  log-format "%ci:%cp [%tr] %ft %b/%s %TR/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Ta %ST %B %CC %CS %tsc %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq %hr %hs %{+Q}r %sslv %sslc %[ssl_fc_cipherlist_str]"
  mode http
  (...)
```

Again, lower security only for debugging if this connection error really is a problem for you.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation. Can you tell me how to solve SSL handshake failure problem? i am initializing like this in frontend: ```bind *:443 ssl crt /path/to/cert.pem alpn h2,http/1.1``` @tbielaszewski

Comment: @manhkhoa168 I updated answer with more info about `/1` naming and proposed path to debug SSL handshake failures.

Comment: so beautiful, thank you! @tbielaszewski